# Can I use a pedal for Casio CTK-1200 keyboard?

Tags: piano, keyboard, keyboard-pedals

I bought Casio CTK-1200 keyboard to learn piano. I am an absolute beginner in the world of music. I just know that Pianos have pedals. But I found that my keyboard didn't come with pedals. I saw that some people just buy pedals and then they can attach them to the keyboard somehow, but I'm not sure if my keyboard supports this.

Can someone tell me if it supports pedals please and which one to buy? www.casio-intl.com/asia-mea/en/emi/standard/ctk1200/spec/

If it doesn't support, do I really need them?!

Comment: Looks like you must upgrade to the CTK-2200 to have the option to add a sustain pedal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the spec., it appears not. The ports are for headphones out and power in. Lots of keyboards do have extra ports for other things, often assignable. Last part - for playing piano, as opposed to most of the other sounds available, the answer is yes, but probably not as a beginner. After some playing,(maybe a year or so, difficult to say), you'll feel the need to see what it does, and how it'll enhance your playing, but it's not exactly as straightforward as just stamping on it when you feel the need. It's maybe easier than on a proper piano, as it works in a more simplified manner, with a lot of not-so-expensive 'boards, but still will only enhance your playing when used properly.

Comment: so basically I wouldn't need this as a beginner. I bought this keyboard just to get started and learn, then once I get really good and know and understand most of those terms in music, then I will upgrade to something decent.

Comment: True - but you will learn far more about the black-and-white bits than playing piano. The feel of a piano (the action) is quite different from a keyboard (unless you spend hundreds).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do really need pedals, at least after the first few months (or less) of playing, depending on how well you progress and if you take lessons or not.

Furthermore, unless you spend a great deal of money, most digital pianos' pedals will not act as an acoustic pedal.  Once you get decent enough at playing, you will find that the digital piano pedal becomes a huge problem since it can't come even close to what an acoustic pedal can do (and acoustic pedal has an infinite number of "damper levels", whereas a digital one naturally will have one or two, or a few more).

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, which if is this specific model supports pedals.